# Debugging & stepping into, dynamic proxies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, spring.net, spring-aop

Does anyone know how to step into the target method of a class that is being managed by (in my case) Spring's AOP mechanism?

If I am stepping through my code and get to e.g. orderDao.FindOrder(orderId), and try and step into that method, I get to the proxy class itself, rather than my OrderDAO.

I understand why that would happen of course. However I'm sure I was able to just step into my method directly at some point (i.e. the debugger is bypassing all the AOP stuff and just going directly to my code.

But it's stopped working, and I have no idea what I could have done to stop it from doing this. A setting in VisualStudio (2010) somewhere perhaps?

I've unchecked and then checked the 'Just my code' option in the debugger to see if that helps, but get the same results.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could make your question a bit broader than only Spring.NET. Spring.NET AOP uses dynamic proxies, which are also used in other stacks (e.g. NHibernate, Castle, LinFu). So formulating your question in a more general so that it would apply there too would attract a larger audience.

Comment: Cheers, good point, I've done that now.

Comment: Look in the Output window.  Does it tell you that it skipped your method intentionally?

Comment: Ahhh, I get this for the Spring DLLs: 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2fb3375e\651711d3\assembly\dl3\4bd45ab3\00a44177_f250cc01\Spring.Web.Mvc3.DLL', Symbols loaded

Comment: And this for the .NET DLLs: 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Razor.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: So I guess I need to figure where this is configured... Google!

Comment: Found it, you can tell VS only to include your own DLLs when debugging in Tools, Options, Debugging, Symbols. Then set up an include/exclude filter by adding each of your DLLs in the 'specified modules' section. Thanks for the heads up Hans. I'd mark you as the correct answer if I could rate comments!

Comment: You can upvote comments too, but maybe you do not enough rep to do that yet. You can answer your own question and accept the answer. Nice solution you found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this in the comments, but just so it's obvious if someone else is looking for a solution...

You can tell VS only to include your own DLLs when debugging in Tools, Options, Debugging, Symbols. Then set up an include/exclude filter by adding each of your DLLs in the 'specified modules' section.

Also, in Tools, Options, Debugging, there is a checkbox called "Just my code". That's probably worth toggling (not sure) but I think it's enabled by default so you might not need to bother with this.